# Cocoa app to publish podcasts vs Mobile friendly site

Tags: xcode, podcasts

I'm not sure of the legal implications of what I am trying to do, but here it goes.

There is a radio show that I love listening to. It comes on everyday and the podcasts are uploaded to a website so users can download and listen to them for free. The website isn't very navigable, however, and it's extremely hard to play the podcasts from my phone (and, therefore, my car).

I have a long commute and I would love it if I could either access these podcasts via some kind of iphone app or maybe even a mobile-friendly website. I am first trying to figure out which would be better (iphone app vs mobile friendly website) and how sketchy you think it would be for me to develop the app (or site) and then offer it to the radio show for them to upload their podcasts. Alternatively, if they didn't want it, I would just download the podcasts from the site and re-upload them to mine.

Please note I am not trying to make any money off this, I am only trying to make it easy for people like me (with long commutes) to enjoy this particular radio show without having to navigate the existing (dysfunctional) site- risking the lives of dogs, squirrels, and other drivers in the process.

Comment: How does the dysfunctional site risk the lives of any dogs, squirrels or other drivers? Sounds like a dysfunctional driver to me. :)

Comment: It's hard to navigate. I try not to do it when I'm driving, but hey, it's a 2 and a half hour commute.

Comment: They don't have a feed so you can subscribe to the podcasts via iTunes?

Comment: or an RSS feed? It might be easier if you give the URL of the radio show so we can see

Comment: I concur with Mark. Having a URL to see the site for ourselves may open up some new ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a podcast if they just upload files and tell you where to find them. The whole point of a podcast is that they are referenced explicitly in a feed of some manner, such that a utility can automatically make them available in whatever manner you need.

Like iTunes for example. It (by default) updates the feed occasionally, and downloads new episodes when they're available, suitable for immediate listening, or sync'ing and listening on-the-go.

Anything else is just silly, and probably means the site operator doesn't really know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of apps on the store that help with podcasting without having to re-host the files.

Have you looked at [Podcaster](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/podcaster-formerly-rss-player/id377195245?mt=8)?

As to hosting them - it's a fine line between you being allowed to download the podcast to your mac and then stream it (time shifting) or sync it (space shift or a copy) to a device to listen away from the computer. If the files are reasonably secured and only accessed to you (so you are not rebroadcasting them to others) you should be on fine ground to defend your actions if anyone decided to sue you.

I would say do whatever makes you the safest on the road so a well designed app to stream from the main server seems like a no-brainer to me rather than setting up a server and re-hosting the files whether or not it's legal.